# Fixing a loop that updates and checks condition on updated data

Tags: r, dataframe, for-loop, dplyr, data.table

I have been trying to write a code that check if condition of a[i-1] and a[i] that will update the b[i] with the value of b[i-1] and c[i], if the condition failed then b[i] must update to 0

My current code is:

```
#R
library(dplyr)
update_b <- function(data) {
  for (i in 2:nrow(data)) {
    if (!is.na(data$a[i]) & !is.na(data$a[i-1]) & data$a[i] < 60 & data$a[i-1] < 60) {
      data$b[i] <- data$c[i] + data$b[i-1]
    } else {
      data$b[i] <- 0
    }
  }
  return(data)
}

result <- data_frame %>%
  group_by(number) %>%
  arrange(date) %>%
  do(update_b(.))
```

It keeps running into:

```
|=============                                                             | 13% \~40 s remaining  
Error in `$<-`:
! Assigned data `*vtmp*` must be compatible with existing data.
x Existing data has 1 row.
x Assigned data has 2 rows.
i Row updates require a list value. Do you need `list()` or `as.list()`?
Caused by error in `vectbl_recycle_rhs_rows()`:
! Can't recycle input of size 2 to size 1.
```

Earlier I have been trying to use data.table to solve this:

```
#R
library(data.table)
calculate_b <- function(x) {
  for (i in 2:nrow(x)) {
    if (x[i, a] < 60 & x[i - 1, a] < 60) {
      x[i, b:= x[i, c] + x[i - 1, b]]
    } else {
      x[i, b:= 0]
    }
  }
  return(x)
}

a[, b:= 0]
a <- a[, calculate_b(.SD), by = number]
```

gave me an error of

```
.SD is locked. Using := in .SD's j is reserved for possible future use; a tortuously flexible way to modify by group. Use := in j directly to modify by group by reference.
```

How could I solve this error?

Edited: This is the data sample

| ID(number) | a | c | b (set as 0 at start) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 30 | 0 | 0 |
| 123 | 25 | 45 | 45 |
| 123 | 18 | 8 | 53 |
| 123 | 80 | 15 | 0 |
| 123 | 45 | 63 | 0 |
| 123 | 15 | 75 | 75 |
| 123 | 70 | 12 | 0 |
| 456 | 65 | 0 | 0 |
| 456 | 45 | 75 | 0 |
| 456 | 30 | 26 | 26 |
| 456 | 58 | 95 | 121 |
| 456 | 53 | 41 | 162 |
| 456 | 50 | 32 | 194 |
| 789 | 45 | 0 | 0 |
| 789 | 90 | 14 | 0 |
| 789 | 89 | 65 | 0 |
| 789 | 75 | 78 | 0 |
| 789 | 80 | 59 | 0 |
| 789 | 50 | 32 | 0 |

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Attempt #3 :-)

This is "rolling" (like attempt 2) by the use of `cumsum`, nothing more. We'll precalculate the points at which `b` should be reset to 0 (calling it `reset`), and then group by consecutive-repeats of this `reset` variable (using `data.table::rleid`).

```r
DT[, reset := is.na(a) | shift(is.na(a), fill=FALSE) | a >= 60 | shift(a >= 60, fill=FALSE), by = .(ID)
  ][, grp := rleid(reset), by = .(ID)
  ][, b := if (reset[1]) 0L else cumsum(c), by = .(ID, grp)]
#        ID     a     c expect  reset   grp     b
#     <int> <int> <int>  <int> <lgcl> <int> <int>
#  1:   123    30     0      0  FALSE     1     0
#  2:   123    25    45     45  FALSE     1    45
#  3:   123    18     8     53  FALSE     1    53
#  4:   123    80    15      0   TRUE     2     0
#  5:   123    45    63      0   TRUE     2     0
#  6:   123    15    75     75  FALSE     3    75
#  7:   123    70    12      0   TRUE     4     0
#  8:   456    65     0      0   TRUE     1     0
#  9:   456    45    75      0   TRUE     1     0
# 10:   456    30    26     26  FALSE     2    26
# 11:   456    58    95    121  FALSE     2   121
# 12:   456    53    41    162  FALSE     2   162
# 13:   456    50    32    194  FALSE     2   194
# 14:   789    45     0      0  FALSE     1     0
# 15:   789    90    14      0   TRUE     2     0
# 16:   789    89    65      0   TRUE     2     0
# 17:   789    75    78      0   TRUE     2     0
# 18:   789    80    59      0   TRUE     2     0
# 19:   789    50    32      0   TRUE     2     0
```

I kept `reset` and `grp` in the output just to show their values, simply remove them with `DT[, c("reset","grp") := NULL]`.

---

Data from your question, renamed for simplicity:

```r
DT <- data.table::as.data.table(structure(list(ID = c(123L, 123L, 123L, 123L, 123L, 123L, 123L, 456L, 456L, 456L, 456L, 456L, 456L, 789L, 789L, 789L, 789L, 789L, 789L), a = c(30L, 25L, 18L, 80L, 45L, 15L, 70L, 65L, 45L, 30L, 58L, 53L, 50L, 45L, 90L, 89L, 75L, 80L, 50L), c = c(0L, 45L, 8L, 15L, 63L, 75L, 12L, 0L, 75L, 26L, 95L, 41L, 32L, 0L, 14L, 65L, 78L, 59L, 32L), expect = c(0L, 45L, 53L, 0L, 0L, 75L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 26L, 121L, 162L, 194L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L)), row.names = c(NA, -19L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame")))
```

Comment: Thanks for your kindly answer,
I'm sorry that I did not provide the clear result I expect, for the function calculate_b you provided did not calculate B based on recent B change in the previous row. 

This link will guide you to the sample table: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1re33rpKlJBo6vcPrM6gSv-6F3WNSA81TJK7W6xPE0N8/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: For further explanation: 
in your formula
since data[, b := 0] will set all row of b to 0
,then all of shift(b,type ="lag") are 0 with no dynamic change.

hope this will explain the previous message

Comment: I would have thought that the _notion_ I used with `shift(.)` and such would be enough to inform you to take it the last mile to your solution. Whether it's `shift(a)` or `shift(b)`, it is just shifting, and since your question is how to deal logically with values on the previous row, then the rest of your logic is just repeating the same mechanism on a different column. Am I mistaken?

Comment: That's correct!

Comment: Oh, you need a ***ROLLING*** calculation, I get it.

Comment: See my edit. Having sample data and expected output is _always_ better and results in a better understanding of what is going on.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255768/discussion-between-lamadiusmozart-and-r2evans).

Comment: See my edit for attempt #3 @LamadiusMozart, I think this should do it for you.

Comment: This is brilliant! Thank you for your magnificent answer and gorgeous will.